# I can't connect to cassandra from nodejs app in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, cassandra

I have a nodejs app inside a docker container (node:7.8.0) using 'bridge' network. I use the cassandra driver to connect with a cassandra server, but it raises timeout exception when initialize the connection:

```
Error: The host 172.16.210.101:9042 did not reply before timeout 12000 ms
    at OperationTimedOutError.DriverError (node_modules/cassandra-driver      /lib/errors.js:14:19)
    at new OperationTimedOutError (node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/errors.js:104:33)
    at Connection.onTimeout (node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/connection.js:645:20)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/connection.js:620:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

From inside the container, I can ping the cassandra server and do a telnet connection.

Using 'host' network works, and executing the app in a "standard" environment too.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Can you show your docker commands?

Comment: I use *sudo docker run -it --rm --name project -p 8080:8080 -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:7.8.0 bash script.sh*, where script.sh do *npm install* and *npm start*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

The MTU of my host machine is 1450, and docker0 uses by default 1500. It produces an error.

So, I change the MTU for docker and it works.

I use a debian host and I followed next steps:

Copy the service file:

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Then, edit the "ExecStart" line like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --mtu=1400
```

Finally, restart docker:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Source:
https://rahulait.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/modifying-default-mtu-for-docker-containers/